# Generating random number between 4 ints

Tags: c++

What is the most efficient way to generate random numbers between 2 ranges?

Comment: What have you tried doing? SO is not a coding service

Comment: Is your question "how to pick a random number between the two given ones"? Why the whole extra information?

Comment: What does efficient mean in your situation?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think he's saying that he want to pick between two ranges, not only one.

Comment: @JérémiPanneton Like do it twice?

Comment: Fastest and memory saver

Comment: I mean i want to pick from 2 ranges

Comment: @EugeneSh. Only once from my understanding. Like picking one number, from one range or the other.

Comment: There are at least two possible approaches. One is to generate a random value and use that to select one of the two ranges, then generate a second random value and use it to select a value from the chosen range. Another is to generate a random value between 0 and the number of values in both ranges, then adjust it to fit the appropriate range.

Comment: @JérémiPanneton Pick two numbers from two ranges once is the same as picking one number twice, no? Well, it is just unclear to me and this is what I voted for... Update: Oh, I see now what you are saying.

Comment: Post an example of how you tried to do it. What i can suggest, is that you can use rand() a firt time to decide which of the two ranges to select from and the second time to select a number in the range. Or use an array of admissible values and extracting random indexes.

Comment: Calculate the total number of values in the two ranges; call that number N.  Now pick a random number between 0 and (N-1).  Then pick the Nth number in the sequence of numbers made up of the concatenation of the two ranges; that is your result.

Comment: You only need to use `rand()` once. Then according to its value you then add one of two offsets.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was writing exactly the same comment at the same time.

Comment: @PeteBecker and they differ in the final distribution if the ranges don't have the same size.

Comment: @FelixPalmen -- not if you "select one of the two ranges" appropriately. There are lots of details I left out in that **sketch**.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it is the same. But in this case, we only want to pick a single number (not twice). The difference being that the possible values this number can be are spread across two different ranges. And yes I do agree, it is in fact unclear. :)

Comment: That actually depends on what you might want your final distribution to be, but since `libc ` (and `C Standards` to be more precise) don't give you any guarantee on distribution of `rand()`, I'd say use everyone's suggestion to choose a number in a range as big as the sum of your two ranges and then bias it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those ranges are inclusive, you have `(r1b-r1a+1)+(r2b-r2a+1)` numbers to choose from. Use `rand` (or a better random number library) to pick a non-negative integer up to `(r1b-r1a+1)+(r2b-r2a+1)` (exclusive), then map that result back onto the ranges.

```
int pick = rand() % ((r1b-r1a+1)+(r2b-r2a+1));
pick += ( pick < (r1b-r1a+1) ) ? r1a : r2a;
```

Assumptions:

- `r1b >= r1a`.
- `r2b >= r2a`.

Supported:

- Range 1 doesn't have to be before range 2.
- Overlapping ranges.
- Negative range endpoints.

Comment: Thanks i will try it